# Links to download the jquery files

Tags: visualforce, jquery

I have to download jquery-1.8.0.min.js,jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.min.js,jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.css or the latest files and i have use it in the code as in the link below

http://thysmichels.com/2013/01/04/visualforce-jquery-datepicker/

I am not getting the particular file which i require and i am confused.

Comment: which particular file you are not getting ?

Comment: Hi himanshu,
I am not getting these files jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.min.js and ,jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.css

Comment: have you uploaded them in static resource ?

Comment: I have not uploaded them yet,i am able to download jquery-1.8.0.min.js. But i am not able to download these 2 files  jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.min.js and jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jquery UI is jquery library and you can download these files from there website.

[**Jquery UI Website**](https://blog.jqueryui.com/2012/08/jquery-ui-1-8-23/)

You can download the latest build from there but if you need those specific version files you can download them from here.

JS:

[jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.min.js](https://code.google.com/p/concerto-platform/source/browse/client/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.min.js?r=791)

css:

[jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.css](https://code.google.com/p/concerto-platform/source/browse/client/css/jQueryUI/cupertino/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.css?r=791)

Comment: save as is not working....Do i need to copy these files code and paste it in notepad and then do i have to use it?

Comment: that is correct.